# looking for a rails example using ajax, simpler the better

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to locate an decent example of ajax json interaction with Rails.  I have a Rails app that uses standard forms and wish to improve it with some ajax, but I have not found a good example to inform me.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you are actually doing?

Comment: Rails is "ajax" out of the box. If you use rails form templates, they hook into prototype Ajax.Updater. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html

Answer (score 0):

I have a large investment portfolio model object, which requires multiple views to input all the data.  I have a mechanism that allows page-to-page transition, using divs with a style of display:none or display:block around wrapping each 'pane'.  I can selectively hide/show each pane as I move off-screen to the next pane.  The user can navigate around, setting values, some of which need to be fetched from the server (such as look up a stock quote).  When all is done, a commit sends it all back to the server, since it is one single form.  So far, so good.

Now, I need to interact with the user when he is picking individual stocks, performing auto-complete on the ticker symbol during typing and then updating a table of stocks picked.  This part has me stumped, since I don't understand how I can get interactive behavior while the input form is displayed.  I am hoping to review some clean examples of ajax interacting with rails.

Oh, by the way, the app is a Facebook application, so I can't use prototype or any rjs templates, but must use FBJS.

I can't seem to find an example that shows ajax updating page sections dynamically.

Comment: Unfortunately, my application is a facebook app, so the prototype js library is incompatible with Facebook's fbjs.